# Can i publish an app using sqlite instead of shared data like google volley?

Tags: android, sqlite

Are there any specifics for the **database** or do I need to switch to **Google volley** and **PHP** for a shared storage option? or is there a way to publish using **sqlite**.

I want shared data usage for all app users.

I have an app I made on Android studio using **sqlite** and is there a way to publish the app without using **Google Volley** for shared data resources, zim new to this.

Comment: just to make the question clear, are you trying to share your application sqlite data with other applications or do want to maintain a central data store which is synced with data from all other users of the application?

Comment: @randomaspirer Im trying to maintain a central data store which is synced for all users, the second option is applicable and can i pulbish without using volley or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use VOLLEY and PHP you have to implement and host the backend.
But you can simply use a service like firebase so you dont need to care about a centralized data store.
Another one is DREAMFACTORY where you can create API end points and can use MLAB (an online mongoDb server) as data store. Those are free and open source.